# Cartthrob php waring Illegal string offset 'onclick' in ft.cartthrob_matrix.php?

Tags: cartthrob

Started seeing this after server upgrade to php 7.1.6

I have CT 3.1 installed.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I know this is due to change to php 7.1.6... Offending line of code is (line 685): $attributes['onclick'] = $onclick;

Answer (score 2):

Ok just in case anybody hits this issue, I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the php version. The server that had this was recently upgraded to 7.1.6. Switching back to 5.x made the warning go away.

A kind person over at StackOverflow found a fix.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204089/illegal-string-offset-with-php-7-1-6/45205713#45205713

Comment: The link you provided fixed it for me as well, thanks for sharing!